# GSAP javascript code works when used in HTML file but breaks when used in React JSX Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using a GSAP.from statement to load in the images of my page from below to their CSS-specified position on the page. For some reason this GSAP useEffect statement completely displaces all the elements of the page. I am translating this code from html and js to a JSX component and this works fine with the HTML. The page will also load normally without the useEffect statement. This is very confusing aswell as GSAP.from shouldn't mess with the end position

```js
import React , {useEffect} from 'react';
import './style.css'; // Import your CSS file here
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
const ParallaxWebsite = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        const parallaxElements = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax");
        const timeline = gsap.timeline();
    
        Array.from(parallaxElements)
          .filter(el => !el.classList.contains("text"))
          .forEach((el) => {
            timeline.from(
              el,
              {
                y: `${el.offsetHeight / 2 + +el.dataset.distance}px`,
                duration: 3.5,
                ease: "power3.out",
              },
              "1"
            );
          });
    
        timeline.from(".text h1", {
          y: window.innerHeight - document.querySelector(".text h1").getBoundingClientRect().top,
          duration: 2,
        }, "2.5")
        .from(".text h2", {
          y: -150,
          opacity: 0,
          duration: 1.5,
        }, "3")
        .from(".hide", {
          opacity: 0,
          duration: 1.5,
        }, "3");
        
        return () => timeline.revert();

      }, []);

    
 

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Responsive 3D Parallax Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <header className="hide">
          <nav>
            <img src={require('./img/logo.png')} alt="Travelo" className="logo" />
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li className="hamburger">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="bar"></div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
          <div className="vingnette"></div>
          <img src={require('./img/background.png')} className="parallax bg-img" data-distance="-75" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_7.png')} className="parallax fog-7" data-distance="850" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_10.png')} className="parallax mountain-10" data-distance="1100" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_6.png')} className="parallax fog-6" data-distance="1400" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_9.png')} className="parallax mountain-9" data-distance="1700" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_8.png')} className="parallax mountain-8" data-distance="1800" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_5.png')} className="parallax fog-5" data-distance="1900" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_7.png')} className="parallax mountain-7" data-distance="2000" />
          <div className="text parallax" data-distance="0">
            <h2>Paarth Kadakia</h2>
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
          </div>
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_6.png')} className="parallax mountain-6" data-distance="2300" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_4.png')} className="parallax fog-4" data-distance="2400" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_5.png')} className="parallax mountain-5" data-distance="2550" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_3.png')} className="parallax fog-3" data-distance="2800" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_4.png')} className="parallax mountain-4" data-distance="3200" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_3.png')} className="parallax mountain-3" data-distance="3400" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_2.png')} className="parallax fog-2" data-distance="3600" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_2.png')} className="parallax mountain-2" data-distance="3800" />
          <img src={require('./img/mountain_1.png')} className="parallax mountain-1" data-distance="4000" />
          <img src={require('./img/sun_rays.png')} className="sun-rays hide" />
          <img src={require('./img/black_shadow.png')} className="black-shadow hide" />
          <img src={require('./img/fog_1.png')} className="parallax fog-1" data-distance="4200" />
        </main>

        <div>asdfasdfasdf</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default ParallaxWebsite;
```